# Setting environment variable for service

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I am running tomcat on a windows 2012 machine.

I need to set an environment variable before the service starts such that I can query the variable in Java in the web application like this:

```
String myVar = System.getenv("MY_VAR");
```

This variable is NOT a tomcat variable.  It is a variable specific to our application.

I am not including tomcat in the tag for this question because this applies to any service; however, I would be happy with a tomcat specific answer.

Here is the question where I asked for a tomcat specific solution:
https://superuser.com/questions/1142406/setting-user-environment-variables-for-tomcat-on-windows

I am using the stand way that Windows manages services that is accessed from the "Administrative Tools" -> "Services" to start and stop tomcat.  So AFAIK, I don't have the usual control I have where I could put the environment variable in a .bat file that also starts the server process.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to set an environment variable just for the service (regardless of what user it's running as) you can do so in the registry: [HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/hklm-system-currentcontrolset-services-registry-tree).

Here's a quick example of using `regedit` to add two environment variables to the Windows Update service (just for demonstration purposes, these aren't affecting the service):

- `FOO=Bar`
- `KEY=SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhIQ==`

[image: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv]
[image: Environment REG_MULTI_SZ]

Start (or restart, if it's already running) the service. We can then use Process Explorer to see that the environment variables are available:

[image: C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs -p -s wuauserv]

Comment: Where has this answer been all my life?! I wish I could give it a million upvotes. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If it is a local Server 2012 environment variable you seek, you can use PowerShell to create a new system or user environment variable make sure you run PowerShell as Administrator.

Machine variable:
`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Name','Value','Machine')`
User variable:
`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Name','Value','User')`

To check the current environment variables, use the following PowerShell command

```
Get-Childitem ENV:
```

Note: you will need to close PowerShell and open a new instance to see the newly created environment variable.

Comment: You only need to restart if you want to use the ENV provider. Set/Create your variable and then just use `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable()` and it will return it with no restart.

Comment: Do we have to reboot windows ? I set in the PowerShell then opened new command prompt window and I can see the environment variable I set, but my service is not picking it up !

Comment: Hi @ChangZhao, you shouldn't need to reboot, The most likely reason the service account cannot see the environment variable is you are running it under a different user account/context.

Comment: @ChangZhao, check out my answer and see if it's more what you were looking for: https://serverfault.com/a/1103091/145894